# Pagination is not working after get request [Laravel 5.3]

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have two methods:

```
public function specific_shop(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $products = Product::where('shop_id', $request->id)->orderBy('quantity', 'asc')->paginate(10);
    return view('product.show', compact('products', 'categories'));

}
public function specific_category(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::where('category_id', $request->id)->orderBy('quantity', 'asc')->paginate(10);
    return view('product.specific', compact('products'));
}
```

The first one is giving me Products from specific shop (after choosing from  select input) and the second one is giving me Products from specific category.

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
Route::get('/product/show/shop/specific', 'ProductController@specific_shop');
Route::get('/product/show/category/specific', 'ProductController@specific_category');
```

Pagination works when I hit /product/ and it shows all  products (not specified) but if I hit /product/show/shop/specific (via form) pagination is not working correctly. It seems like it doesn't even work at all. First page is fine but if I click next, it returns nothing. Blank table. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
 $id = $request->id;
return view('product.specific', compact('products','id'));
```

Then in your view instead of

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

Do this

```
{{ $products->appends(['id' => $id])->links() }}
```

Issue : the id field is not being passed to the second page i guess.

Also it's better to put the ressource route at the bottom to avoid any trouble

```
Route::get('/product/show/shop/specific', 'ProductController@specific_shop');
Route::get('/product/show/category/specific', 'ProductController@specific_category');
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.